# Sort List by Enum type property using extension method - ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created an API using ASP.NET Core 6. There is a requirement to add sorting functionality to the API. I have added the functionality but I had two issues with that. One is already fixed by posting the issue on Stackoverflow. I was struggling to fix the second issue but no luck. So I ended up here.

The API manipulates the store products. I have added the sorting functionality to the `getAllProducts(list)` endpoint by using an extension method.

`Product` entity:

```
public class Product
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }  
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public ProductStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

`ProductStatus` enum:

```
public enum ProductStatus
{
    Inactive = 0,
    Active = 1
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> list, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
{
    string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    var type = typeof(TEntity);
    var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
        list.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
    return list.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
}
```

Extension method call:

```
productsList = productsList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Category", true).ToList();
```

Even though I have hardcoded the order property and sorting condition here, those values accepts from query parameters, making the sorting dynamic. Sorting now works fine with all product's properties except the enum property.

If I call the extension method with enum property like this:

```
productsList = productsList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("status", false).ToList();
```

List sorts as all the inactive products first and Active products next. it's because the sorting considers the enum int value not the enum as string values.

I want to customize the extension method so that the data list sorted with enum field(as strings -> Active and Inactive) like all other properties. I expect your help. Thank You!.

Comment: Why are you using an extension method rather than linq orderby and chained linq.

Comment: It's because sorting need to be dynamic. sorting order and property gets from query params.

Comment: Chaining linq allows you to pick which . method you use dynamically.  More code but simpler code.  You could alternatively use a custom icomparer and put whatever logic you like in the icomparer.  As it is you have some fairly complicated code there and a problem.

Comment: There is also an existing `Linq.Dynamic` extension which allows you to use `.OrderBy("myProp asc")` for example